# Set border to component extends JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I try to create my own `YTextField`, I extend my class to `JTextField` and I want to set a new border when `FocusListener` :

Here is my code :

```
public class YTextField extends JTextField {

    public YTextField() {
        super();
        super.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14));
        FocusListener highlighter = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                //Set my border
                Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
                super.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder(border));
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //Set the default border
                super.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));

            }
        };
        super.addFocusListener(highlighter);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to create this component so I can set my border `focusGained` for example?

Comment: You can directly put  on focus gained`setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));`

and `.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());` on focus lost

Comment: it work, this is amazing thank you so much @BOUALIALI this is really helped me

Comment: I will post it as an answer and you ca check it as a solution, so others can directly find out if they have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly put on focus gained

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
```

and

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

on focus lost

Good luck